# How to fix Android SDK buid tools version too low with terminal?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My english is not very good, thx for your reading :)

"The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project",this error always show when I reinstall some modules. I know this error is caused by gradle version.

Usually, I just click Android Studio error tip to fix this problem, just like the blow picture shows.

***The error tip***

[image: the error tip]

And I know AS modify my modules code to the recommended version, but i don't know the inner process.

I know another way is using the highest sdk build tool verison to config the main project's gradle setting and make sub project to read the main project's instead of own. just like [this way](https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/how-to-permanently-fix-sdk-build-tools-is-too-low-for-project-error-in-react-native-for-android-1a2d245bda18)

But, I worry about this way may cause some compatibility problem in the future.

I think the best way is what AS do

So, I really want to know what Android Studio do, can I use some AS command and gradle command to fix this error automatically?

Or my worry about compatibility is wrong?

Comment: can you post build.gradle and app level gradle files of your project?

Comment: You don't need to worry about compatibility issues, because anything that is supported in build tools version 23.0.3 is also supported in build tools version 25.0.0, as it is upgraded version.

Comment: @MeghaManiar, thx for your answer. Is large version span also ok? my knowledge about gradle is much less.

Comment: @ShivaMuruganS thx for your response. i know that gradle version causes this issue.